# How to Call user-defined Lambda Function in Java

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-11, jshell

In [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html), I saw an example of a user-defined lambda function.

```
Function<String, String> toLowerCase = (var input) -> input.toLowerCase();
```

What I am wondering is how can I call this function? I tried it in jshell but am unable to. I can create the function fine :

Any ideas?

```
jshell> Function<String, String> toLowerCase = (var input) -> input.toLowerCase();
toLowerCase ==> $Lambda$16/0x00000008000b3040@3e6fa38a
```

but can't seem to execute it :

```
jshell> String hi = "UPPER";
jshell> String high;
high ==> null

jshell> toLowerCase(high,low);
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   method toLowerCase(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
|  toLowerCase(high,low);
|  ^---------^

jshell>
```

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a `Function` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an instance, type of a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) functional interface, which has a method [`Function.apply()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-). Therefore, you have to use it in the same way you'd use in a Java class:

```
toLowerCase.apply(high);
```

What in the `toLowerCase(high,low);` made you think the `low` is? Like in Java, you have to work with the defined methods and variables in the available scope.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `apply` the Function such as:

```
toLowerCase.apply(high)
```

[image]

or assign its value to another variable `low` as in:

```
jshell> String low = toLowerCase.apply(high)
low ==> "ggggg"
```

---

---

***Suggestion***: Use `jshell` auto-completion (with tab key on macOS) to figure out what all methods are applicable to be called on the variables declared.

[image]